# JNI method static resolution verification

Tags: java, android, reflection, java-native-interface

I am wondering is it possible to verify in Java under the Android SDK that a method in a Java class implemented as a native JNI method was resolved statically? Below there is an explanation of what I am looking for.

I have a Java class that is partially implemented as a JNI class. This class can be initialized statically if the corresponding JNI library has been created as a static library (libhelper.a, for instance). Or it can be initialized dynamically if the corresponding JNI library is implemented as a dynamic library (libhelper.so, for instance). In case of dynamic initialization the class should have a static initializer that loads the dynamic library – libhelper.so. I am using both case and I want to keep the same source code for both of them. For this purpose I would like to verify in the static initializer if the corresponding native methods has been already resolved. If it is true, I do not need to load dynamic library.  If it is false, it means that I have to load dynamic library. The problem is I do not know how to verify that a method in the class has been already resolved.

The sample below has incorrect lines, that show my intention.

```
package com.sample.package;
public class MyUtilityClass 
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyUtilityClass";
    public MyUtilityClass () {
        Log.v(TAG, " MyUtilityClass constructor");     
    }
    public static native int initMyHelperClass();
    public static native int performHelpAction(String action);
    public static native int uninitMyHelperClass();

    static {
        try {
            /* Here I want to verify that the native method 
               initMyHelperClass has has been already resolved.
               In this code snippet I am just comparing it to null,
               which is not correct. It should be something different. */ 
            if (initMyHelperClass == null) {
                /* initMyHelperClass has not been resolved yet,
                   load the dynamic library - libhelper.so */            
                System.loadLibrary("helper");
            }   
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
            /*Library not found. We should throw second exception. */
            throw ule;  
        }     
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a static library.  JNI is always loaded using a dynamic library.  Or are you relinking your JVM?

Comment: Hi Keith, You were right. My question is incorrect. I need to reformulate it. It is not related to a static library. It is about verification, that the particular JNI method is resolved and does not require additional library load. 

Let say I have two approaches:
(1) One dynamic library libcombined.so that includes libhelper.a and other static libraries.
(2) Several dynamic libraries loaded on demand when an object for the particular class is being created. libhelper.so is one of them. In case (1) I do not need to load libhelper.so.
In case (2) I need to load libhelper.so.

Comment: So please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UnsatisfiedLinkError` and a dummy method to check if a given class' native methods are loaded:

```
private static native void checkMe();  // does nothing

static {
    try {
        checkMe();
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.loadLibrary("checkLibrary");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works although it looks a bit like a hack. There is another way is just to verify libhelper.so existence but your way is more clear, I think. Cheers.